# Faded text on featured questions page - what's up?

Tags: discussion, support, homepage

On the featured questions page of Stack Exchange sites, sometimes I see a question that has faded text like so (Super User):
[image]

What's up with that?  What does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have one of the tags on that question in your ignored tag list.

Comment: ahhh, that makes sense! I don't know much about SSH, so it is on my ignored list...that's the reverse of the highlighted blues...Thanks!