# Why do some questions in SO now have a pink background?

Tags: support, user-interface

Title say it all. This seemed to happen in the past 24 hours.

Comment: This **has** to be a dupe :)

Comment: I searched and didn't find it.

Comment: perhaps not an *exact* dupe, but you get the point: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71394/faded-text-on-featured-questions-page-whats-up

Comment: If you have not set any favorite tags, then see also [Why is stack overflow suddenly orange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593) Possibly also related (but also old): [Stack Overflow Homepage Changes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/).

Comment: Pink?  Your eyes, get them checked.

Comment: @Will orangish pink. Of course my Lenovo W500 LCD is not calibrated.

Comment: "Very Pale Amber" cite: http://www.perbang.dk/rgb/FFEFC6/

Comment: @Mark: +1, that's a great site.

Comment: oops can't +1 here.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod - it is sometimes useful to fill out your profile and connect it to the other SO sites :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean like this?

[image]

If it is in pink, it is one of your interesting tags (see sidebar on the top questions page - it lists your favorite and ignored tags).

I needed some ignored and interesting questions (for the screenshot), so just picked what was out there - *I'm not really ignoring that category, only temporarily for the screenshot*. :-)

Comment: Damn if that is pink I'm as colorblind as the next dog! isn't that yellow? :)

Comment: Aaaahhh this got me all excited for whole pages of stackoverflow in pink.

Comment: red: 255 green: 239 blue: 198, I think that's pink

Comment: Wait, so interesting doesn't mean you've selected the tag as a "Favorite" in your prefs?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: That's the same thing. "Interesting tags" were recently renamed to "Favorite tags"

Comment: sorry, my bad - favorite = interesting in this post.  @ThomasMcLeod

Comment: the CSS class is .tagged-interesting with a #ffefc6 value.